# Math operation with dynamical sign

Tags: javascript

I want to do a random math task with a random math operation sign in the middle.

The Random Numbers are fine. I do it with:

```
function getRandomInt(min, max) 
{
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
}
```

and save this return into var number1 and number2

Now the problem.

```
const mathOperationList = ['+', '-', '*', '/'];
function getRandomOperation()
{
  var randomMathOperation = mathOperationList[Math.floor(Math.random() * mathOperationList.length)];
  return randomMathOperation;
}

var mathOperation = getRandomOperation();
console.log("What is "+number1 + " "+mathOperation+" "+number2 +"?");
mathResult = number1 +mathOperation+ number2;
console.log(mathResult)
```

Output is: "1+1" (not 2)

The output is a string and not a ResultInt. I know the number1+mathOperation+number2 are do it but I want a mathResult and not a String together.

How can i fix it?

Comment: why not passing the two numbers to the `getRandomOperation` and let it return the result, for instance you can do a switch statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `eval` function which evaluates arbitrary JavaScript code as a string.

**Warning**: `eval` is VERY dangerous due to XSS vulnerabilities and should never be used to execute non-serialized user input.

```js
const number1 = 3, number2 = 4;

const mathOperationList = ['+', '-', '*', '/'];
function getRandomOperation()
{
  var randomMathOperation = mathOperationList[Math.floor(Math.random() * mathOperationList.length)];
  return randomMathOperation;
}

const mathOperation = getRandomOperation();
console.log("What is "+number1 + " "+mathOperation+" "+number2 +"?");
const mathResult = eval(`${number1}${mathOperation}${number2}`);
console.log(mathResult);
```

Using switch-case (safer)

```js
const number1 = 3, number2 = 4;

const mathOperationList = ['+', '-', '*', '/'];
function getRandomOperation()
{
  var randomMathOperation = mathOperationList[Math.floor(Math.random() * mathOperationList.length)];
  return randomMathOperation;
}

function performOperation(left, right, operator) {
  switch (operator) {
    case "+":
      return left + right;
    case "-":
      return left - right;
    case "*":
      return left * right;
    case "/":
      return left / right;
  }
}

const mathOperation = getRandomOperation();
console.log("What is "+number1 + " "+mathOperation+" "+number2 +"?");
const mathResult = performOperation(number1, number2, mathOperation);
console.log(mathResult);
```

Answer (score 0):

#### What not to do

You should not use `eval()` as it can introduces serious security issues and it is just bad practice. In your case there is not much risk as the values **at the moment** are not supplied by a user, but once they are you can get into serious trouble.

Let's assume you let users provide values for number and you don't check them appropriately then the following would constitute a successful **Denial of Service (DoS)** attack on your program because this will cause an infinite loop.

```js
const number1 = "for(;;);";
const mathOperation = "+";
const number2 = 2;
eval(number1 + mathOperation + number2);
```

It also opens up other attack vectors, so just don't use `eval()`.

#### What to do instead

Instead declare an array of functions, one function for every operation and randomly choose one function.

```js
function getRandomInt(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
}

const mathOperationList = [
  { func: (a, b) => a + b, symbol: "+" },
  { func: (a, b) => a - b, symbol: "-" },
  { func: (a, b) => a * b, symbol: "*" },
  { func: (a, b) => a / b, symbol: "/" },
];

function getRandomOperation() {
  const randomMathOperation =
    mathOperationList[Math.floor(Math.random() * mathOperationList.length)];
  return randomMathOperation;
}

const { func: mathOperation, symbol } = getRandomOperation();
const number1 = getRandomInt(1, 10);
const number2 = getRandomInt(1, 10);
console.log("What is " + number1 + " " + symbol + " " + number2 + "?");
const mathResult = mathOperation(number1, number2);
console.log(mathResult);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could take an object with all functions and get the operator first.

```js
const
    getRandomOperator = () => operators[Math.floor(Math.random() * operators.length)],
    operators = ['+', '-', '*', '/'],
    functions = {
        '+': (a, b) => a + b,
        '-': (a, b) => a - b,
        '*': (a, b) => a * b,
        '/': (a, b) => a / b
    },
    operator = getRandomOperator(),
    number1 = 10,
    number2 = 5,
    result = functions[operator](number1, number2);

console.log(`What is ${number1} ${operator} ${number2}?`);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score -1):

One way to use `switch` case and I would recommend this.

```js
function calculate(a, b, operation) {
   switch(operation) {
      case "+":
        return a + b;
      case "-":
        return a - b;
   }
}
```

Another way to use [eval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) through which we can execute some JS code from string.

> Executing JavaScript from a string is an enormous security risk.

**Example:**  `eval("1+1")`